# UIMenu doen't change its value if the user selects an element for the second time

Tags: swift, uimenu

I have the code below that shows a list for the user with 5 options. After the user selects an option for the first time, it show a list with 4 options.

But if the user selecta a new option for the second or third time, the values don't change.

```
fileprivate func configMenu() {
    
    let optionClosure = { [weak self]
        ( action : UIAction ) in
        print("v000: \(action.title)")
        if action.title != "Selecione a chave" {
            
            self?.accountTypePopUpButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [
                UIAction(title: "CPF/CNPJ", handler: { _ in } ),
                UIAction(title: "Celular", handler: { _ in } ),
                UIAction(title: "E-mail", handler: { _ in } ),
                UIAction(title: "Chave aleatória", handler: { _ in } ),                    
            ])
            self?.accountTypeFilled = true
            self?.accountType = action.title
            self?.accountTypePopUpButton.reloadInputViews()
        }

    }
    
    accountTypePopUpButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [
        UIAction(title: "Selecione a chave", handler: optionClosure),
        UIAction(title: "CPF/CNPJ", handler: optionClosure),
        UIAction(title: "Celular", handler: optionClosure),
        UIAction(title: "E-mail", handler: optionClosure),
        UIAction(title: "Chave aleatória", handler: optionClosure),
    ])
    
    accountTypePopUpButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
    accountTypePopUpButton.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
    
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what fix the code for me.

```
    let optionClosure = { [weak self] ( action : UIAction ) in
        print("v000: \(action.title)")
        if action.title != "Selecione a chave pix" {
            self?.accountTypePopUpButton.setTitleColor(.savvyBlack, for: .normal)
            self?.accountTypePopUpButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [
                UIAction(title: "CPF/CNPJ", handler: { [weak self] ( myAction : UIAction ) in self?.setActionValues(myAction.title) } ),
                UIAction(title: "Celular", handler: { [weak self] ( myAction : UIAction ) in self?.setActionValues(myAction.title) } ),
                UIAction(title: "E-mail", handler: { [weak self] ( myAction : UIAction ) in self?.setActionValues(myAction.title) } ),
                UIAction(title: "Chave aleatória", handler: { [weak self] ( myAction : UIAction ) in self?.setActionValues(myAction.title) } ),
            ])
            self?.setActionValues(action.title)
        }

    }

fileprivate func setActionValues(_ actionTitle: String) {
    dprint("actionTitle v1: \(actionTitle)")
    accountTypeFilled = true
    accountType = actionTitle
    accountTypePopUpButton.reloadInputViews()
}
```

To fix my code what I need is to modify the empty handler code

```
handler: { _ in }
```

to

```
handler: { [weak self] ( myAction : UIAction ) in self?.setActionValues(myAction.title) }
```

When I modify this handler, the code starts working for me.

To fix my code I just need to put a code inside the handler. The 2nd handler is where I need to run my code after it change the Menu options.

Answer (score 0):

```
fileprivate func configMenu() {

var selectionCount = 0

let optionClosure = { [weak self]
    ( action : UIAction ) in
    print("v000: \(action.title)")
    
    if action.title != "Selecione a chave" {
        // Update menu only if the user hasn't selected an option before
        if selectionCount == 0 {
            self?.accountTypePopUpButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [
                UIAction(title: "CPF/CNPJ", handler: { _ in } ),
                UIAction(title: "Celular", handler: { _ in } ),
                UIAction(title: "E-mail", handler: { _ in } ),
                UIAction(title: "Chave aleatória", handler: { _ in } ),
            ])
            self?.accountTypePopUpButton.reloadInputViews()
        }
        
        self?.accountTypeFilled = true
        self?.accountType = action.title
        selectionCount += 1
    }
}

accountTypePopUpButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [
    UIAction(title: "Selecione a chave", handler: optionClosure),
    UIAction(title: "CPF/CNPJ", handler: optionClosure),
    UIAction(title: "Celular", handler: optionClosure),
    UIAction(title: "E-mail", handler: optionClosure),
    UIAction(title: "Chave aleatória", handler: optionClosure),
])

accountTypePopUpButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
accountTypePopUpButton.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true

}
```

This is how you can modify your code and get it fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.

Comment: At least, the way that you the "selectionCount" is different than my validation and I think it's a good way of validation.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**